# How can you configure windows to Auto Logon with specific username and password?

Tags: windows, login

There are some scenarios for which you want to configure a machine to automatically login using a specific user account and password without blocking on the logon screen. How does one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Use Autologon from Sysinternals**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx

2. **Configure autologon on Vista**

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsvista/ht/autologonvista.htm

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP autologin.  This procedure also works for Win2k as well.  You can bypass this method by holding the shift key when logging in or out of the system.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

Answer (score 1):

In XP:

> start -> run -> "control userpasswords2"

Comment: Vista too (same as the linked netplwiz)